# Very many , when to use

Tags: adverbs

> In fact, very many people think differently.

I read that **very** can be used to intensify "many", but I don't often come across it in the texts. Where can it be used, in formal or colloquial speech?

Comment: My guess is people don't use emphatic ***very** many* as often as you might expect because *in many contexts* it's not actually all that emphatic (it can't really be useful in *that* many contexts, or I'd have been able to confidently say ***in most contexts***). So really it's a bit "weak", like saying something happened ***quite a few times*** when you can't justify claiming it happened ***often***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What should be used instead? A great many?

Comment: As I just tried to explain, if your context can't justify using ***most***, you might be better not calling attention to it by trying to "amplify" ***many*** when it's obvious you're not even talking about the majority. In almost all cases, this is nothing to do with "numerical accuracy" - it's about "persuasive writing", where you'd probably weaken your case by giving the reader / audience pause to note that ***very many*** is a desperate attempt to "inflate" some value which is contextually unlikely to represent even the majority, let alone ***almost all***.

Comment: ...having said that, you might want to consider using something like [*a **significant number of** people think otherwise*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+significant+number+of+people+think%22) But this really is a matter of "writing advice" rather than "learning English" as such.

Comment: No, it's about usage, as a matter of fact, I couldn't find the information  anywhere,  thanks a lot.

Comment: On the "usage, stylistic choice" front I think it's probably fair to say ***very many*** is more likely in *negating* contexts such as *I haven't seen very many good Korean films* (for reasons that aren't precisely obvious to me, ***very*** doesn't sit well in non-negated *I have seen very many good Korean films*). But I'd probably prefer ***a lot of*** there anyway - even without ***very***, ***many*** sounds just a little "florid, poetic".